# razor-pages Delete functional doesn't work, how to delete?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I'm currently learning RazorPages in codeacademy.com.
I did everything that was shown in the video Tutorial, and unfortunately is doesn't work:

The task for the project:
"Data Delete
The current project has a button on the Index page list that deletes the current Continent or Country. The button will be modified to call a discrete Delete.cshtml page. This page will display the current record for review and provide a Delete button. Once the deletion occurs, the user is redirected back to the list so they get visual feedback of a successful task.

The code and markup are easily copied from the existing Detail.cshtml page. After copying that page, we add a delete button and copy the necessary statements from the OnPostAsync() method in the Index.cshtml.cs page."
The Delete page was created. The problem is:
When I press button Delete on the Delete page I have redirection to this link in browser:

https://localhost/Continents/Delete/SA?Continent.ID=SA

Actually no Delete happends
No redirection

What mistakes maybe here?

The code Delete.cshtml:

```
@page "{id}"
@model DeleteModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Continent Delete";
}

<div class="jumbotron p-3">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <h1 class="display-4 flex-grow-1">
      Continent Delete
    </h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="./Index">
      Back to List
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFnrX.jpg)
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="p-2 bg-primary text-white text-right" style="flex:0 0 15%">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Continent.ID)
  </div>
  <div class="p-2 border-top border-right border-bottom border-primary" style="flex:1 0 auto">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Continent.ID)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="p-2 bg-primary text-white text-right" style="flex:0 0 15%">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Continent.Name)
  </div>
  <div class="p-2 border-right border-bottom border-primary" style="flex:1 0 auto">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Continent.Name)
  </div>
</div>

<form metod="post" class="d-flex flex-row-reverse mt-3">
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="Continent.ID"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"/>
</form>
```

Delete.cshtml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RazorCountry.Models;
using RazorCountry.Data;

namespace RazorCountry.Pages.Continents
{
  public class DeleteModel : PageModel
  {
    private readonly CountryContext _context;

    public DeleteModel(CountryContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    public Continent Continent { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
    {
      Continent = await _context.Continents
        .Include(c => c.Countries)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

      if (Continent == null)
      {
        return NotFound();
      }

      return Page();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string id)
    {
      if (id == null)
      {
        return NotFound();
      }
      // Find the continent
      Continent Continent = await _context.Continents.FindAsync(id);
      //Delete the continent
      if (Continent != null)
      {
        _context.Continents.Remove(Continent);
      }
      //Persist Changes
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      //Redirect to the user
      return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
  }
}
```

Model Continent.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RazorCountry.Models
 {
public class Continent
  {
[Required, StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2), Display(Name = "Code")]
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Z]+", ErrorMessage = "Only upper case characters are allowed.")]
public string ID { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }

public ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
  }
 }
```

Try to understand how RazorPages functional works, try to fix mistake in a correct way

Answer (score 0):

The reason that no error occurs is because your `OnPostAsync` method is not being hit. You have mis-spelled the `method` attribute in your form (you have `metod`) so submitting it generates the default `GET` request and your `OnGetAsync` handler is executed instead.

Once you have corrected that error, you still have an unresolved issue.

Your `OnPostAsync` handler expects a parameter named `id`. The hidden field tag helper in your form generates a parameter with a name of `Continent.ID`. Consequently the value will not be bound to the `id` parameter. The simplest solution is to do away with the tag helper in the form a the bottom of your Delete page and replace it with a plain HTML input with a `name` attribute:

```
<form method="post" class="d-flex flex-row-reverse mt-3">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Continent.ID"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"/>
</form>
```

You can read more about model binding in general here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: Thank you very much,the problem with "method" spelling